# Why is LSTM implemented in tensorflow so slow as compared to pure pythonic implementation

Tags: lstm

I am trying to implement word level prediction, an adaptation of from http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/. When I implement it in pure python, the training is fast. However I started learning tensorflow and I tried to implement the same in tensorflow(eager execution). However, the training is extremely slow. A my the one who has done things wrong ? Please advise. Here is the code. I am running the code in CPU mac

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython import display
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython import display
class RNN_LSTM(object):
    def __init__(self,hidden_size):
        data=open('Shakespear.txt', 'r').read() 
        self.data = data.split()
        vocab_size=len(list(set(self.data)))
        self.words =list(set(self.data))
        self.hidden_size=hidden_size
        self.input_size=vocab_size+hidden_size
        self.vocab_size=vocab_size
        self.W1=tf.Variable(tf.random.normal((self.hidden_size,self.input_size))*0.1,dtype=tf.dtypes.float32,name="W1")
        self.b1=tf.Variable(tf.random.normal((self.hidden_size,1))*0.1,dtype=tf.dtypes.float32,name="b1")
        self.W2=tf.Variable(tf.random.normal((self.hidden_size,self.input_size))*0.1,dtype=tf.dtypes.float32,name="W2")
        self.b2=tf.Variable(tf.random.normal((self.hidden_size,1))*0.1,dtype=tf.dtypes.float32,name="b2")
        self.W3=tf.Variable(tf.random.normal((self.hidden_size,self.input_size))*0.1,dtype=tf.dtypes.float32,name="W3")
        self.b3=tf.Variable(tf.random.normal((self.hidden_size,1))*0.1,dtype=tf.dtypes.float32,name="b3")
        self.W4=tf.Variable(tf.random.normal((hidden_size,self.input_size))*0.1,dtype=tf.dtypes.float32,name="W4")
        self.b4=tf.Variable(tf.random.normal((self.hidden_size,1))*0.1,dtype=tf.dtypes.float32,name="b4")
        self.W5=tf.Variable(tf.random.normal((self.vocab_size,self.hidden_size))*0.1,dtype=tf.dtypes.float32,name="W5")
        self.b5=tf.Variable(tf.random.normal((self.vocab_size,1))*0.1,dtype=tf.dtypes.float32,name="b5")
        self.learning_rate=0.1
        self.sequence_length=25 
        self.selection_sample_np=[i for i in range(self.vocab_size)]
        self.selection_sample_tf=tf.convert_to_tensor(self.selection_sample_np)
        self.char_to_ix={ch:ix for ix,ch in enumerate(self.words)}
        self.ix_to_char={ix:ch for ix,ch in enumerate(self.words)}



    def feedforward(self,X,Y,hprev,p_s):

        losses=0
        for x,y in zip(X,Y):

            M_c=tf.Variable(tf.zeros((self.input_size,1)),name="M_c") 
            h=tf.one_hot(x,self.vocab_size)
            gh=tf.reshape(h,(self.vocab_size,1))
            M_c=tf.concat((hprev,gh),axis=0)  
            ft=tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(self.W1,M_c)+self.b1)
            it=tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(self.W2,M_c)+self.b2)
            gt=tf.math.tanh(tf.matmul(self.W3,M_c)+self.b3)
            cs=tf.multiply(ft,p_s)+tf.multiply(it,gt)
            ot=tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(self.W4,M_c)+self.b4)
            ht=tf.multiply(ot,tf.math.tanh(cs))
            output=tf.matmul(self.W5,ht)+self.b5
            yt = tf.nn.softmax(output,axis=0)
            losses=losses+(-tf.math.log(yt[y]))
            hprev=ht
            p_s=cs

        return ht,cs,output,losses





    def process_data(self,p):
        inputs=[self.char_to_ix[ch] for ch in self.data[p:p+self.sequence_length]]
        targets=[self.char_to_ix[ch] for ch in self.data[p+1:p+self.sequence_length+1]]
        features=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(inputs)
        labels=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(targets)
        training_data=tf.data.Dataset.zip((features,labels)).batch(25)
        return training_data
    def sample_text(self,hprev,begin,p_s,n):
        selected_letters=[]
        for i in range(n):
            M=tf.Variable(tf.zeros((self.input_size,1)),name="M")
            h=tf.one_hot(begin,self.vocab_size)
            gh=tf.reshape(h,(self.vocab_size,1))
            M=tf.Variable(tf.zeros((self.input_size,1)),name="M")
            M=tf.concat((hprev,gh),axis=0)
            ft=tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(self.W1,M)+self.b1)
            it=tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(self.W2,M)+self.b2)
            gt=tf.math.tanh(tf.matmul(self.W3,M)+self.b3)
            cs=tf.multiply(ft,p_s)+tf.multiply(it,gt)
            ot=tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(self.W4,M)+self.b4)
            ht=tf.multiply(ot,tf.math.tanh(cs))
            output=tf.matmul(self.W5,ht)+self.b5
            p=tf.nn.softmax(output,axis=0)
            p=tf.reshape(p.numpy(),(1,self.vocab_size))
            samples =tf.random.categorical(tf.log(p.numpy()), 1)
            sample_selected=samples[0][0]
            selected_next_letter=self.selection_sample_tf[sample_selected]
            hprev=ht
            p_s=cs
            begin=selected_next_letter
            selected_letters.append(selected_next_letter)
        return selected_letters 
    def lossFun(x):
        loss=0
        return loss.assign_add(x)


    def softmax(self,z):
        return tf.math.exp(z-tf.reduce_max(z))/tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.exp(z-tf.reduce_max(z)))
    def Bonga(self):


        p=0
        i=0
        smooth_loss =-np.log(1.0/self.vocab_size)*self.sequence_length





        while(1):
            with tf.GradientTape() as g:
                g.watch([self.W1,self.W2,self.W3,self.W4,self.W5,self.b1,self.b2,self.b3,self.b4,self.b5])
                if p+self.sequence_length+1>= len(self.data) or i == 0: 
                        hprev=tf.Variable(np.zeros((self.hidden_size,1)),dtype=tf.float32)
                        p_s=tf.Variable(tf.zeros((self.hidden_size,1)))
                        p=0

                training_dataset=self.process_data(p)
                for batch in tfe.Iterator(training_dataset):
                    begin=batch[0][0]
                    hprev,p_s,output,loss=self.feedforward(batch[0],batch[1],hprev,p_s)
                    training_dataset=self.process_data(p)

            optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(
            learning_rate=self.learning_rate,decay=0.9,momentum=0.01, epsilon=1e-8,use_locking=False,centered=False,
                name='RMSProp')
            grad = g.gradient(loss,[self.W1,self.W2,self.W3,self.W4,self.W5,self.b1,self.b2,self.b3,self.b4,self.b5])
            capped_gvs = [(tf.clip_by_value(g, -1.0, 1.0)) for g in grad]
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(capped_gvs,[self.W1,self.W2,self.W3,self.W4,self.W5,self.b1,self.b2,self.b3,self.b4,self.b5]))


            if i % 100 == 0:
                sample_ix = self.sample_text(hprev,begin,p_s,200)
                text=[self.ix_to_char[ix.numpy()] for ix in sample_ix]
                txt = tf.strings.join(text,separator=" ")
                print ('----\n %s \n----' % (txt.numpy(),  ))
                smooth_loss = smooth_loss * 0.999 + loss * 0.001
                print ('iterr %d, loss: %f' % (i, smooth_loss))
            i=i+1
            p=p+self.sequence_length
```